# DNS lookup spam running up Route 53 bill

Tags: domain-name-system, spam, amazon-route53, dns-hosting

Throughout 21 we saw around 15M DNS queries/month. In January 2022 we saw almost 300M and I didn't notice.... then February almost 1 BILLION...... and I noticed because of the bill. Amazon isn't really helping yet I told them this is obviously spam.

This isn't application layer there is nothing I can do right...?

Comment: Route53 doesn't charge for some record types - things like A and AAAA or Alias records pointing at AWS resources. Maybe review what records you have and see if you can adjust them?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/en/route53/pricing/ @shearn89 i think thats not entirely true

Comment: One billion or one trillion? AWS pricing calculator refuses to exceed 10 billion.

Comment: @djdomi - that's the page I checked: "DNS queries are free when both of the following are true:

    The domain or subdomain name (example.com or acme.example.com) and the record type (A) in the query match an alias record.
    The alias target is an AWS resource other than another Route 53 record."

Comment: @djdomi - my mistake indeed ~1 billion or 980,441,652 queries in February. Still definitely an attack... not legit traffic.

Comment: i eould maybe contact the support instead and ask for a detailed invoice and moreover how to prevent such attempts?!

Comment: Just an update - confirmed an attack being spammed with literally up to 38M+ lookups of random junk subdomains in an hour. https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/dns-flood-ddos-attack/ am talking to Amazon. CloudFlare DNS is free so if Amazon won't do anything and wants to keep charging seems the solution is to move away.